# PL/SQL function in Oracle cannot see DBMS_AQ

Tags: oracle, plsql, jms, advanced-queuing

I have problem with Oracle 9.2 and JMS.
I created PL/SQL routine to send XML text (from file or CLOB) to queue,
but this routine do not compile.

My code looks like (filling message omitted):

```
create or replace procedure jms_test(msg varchar2)
is
    id                 pls_integer;
    message            sys.aq$_jms_stream_message;
    enqueue_options    dbms_aq.enqueue_options_t;
    message_properties dbms_aq.message_properties_t;
    msgid raw(16);

    java_exp           exception;
    v_filehandle_input utl_file.file_type;
    v_newline     varchar2(32767);
    pragma exception_init(java_exp, -24197);
begin
    message := sys.aq$_jms_stream_message.construct;
    message.set_string_property('FROM', 'TEST');
    id := message.clear_body(-1);
end;
```

And Oracle raports that:

```
Error(6,21): PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_AQ' must be declared
```

I looked at some newsgroups and tried all that I found, but with no success.

1. granted (with success) many permisions

   - GRANT RESOURCE TO user;
   - GRANT CONNECT TO user;
   - GRANT EXECUTE ANY PROCEDURE TO user;
   - GRANT aq_administrator_role TO user;
   - GRANT aq_user_role TO user;
   - GRANT EXECUTE ON dbms_aqadm TO user;
   - GRANT EXECUTE ON dbms_aq TO user;
   - GRANT EXECUTE ON dbms_aqin TO user;
2. desc dbms_aq shows many functions like DEQUEUE, ENQUEUE, LISTEN
3. executed in SQLPlus both catqueue.sql and dbmsaq.plb

Anybody have idea what can be wrong?

**EDITED**:

I can do all that is described in: http://rwijk.blogspot.com/2009/02/whats-in-my-jms-queue.html, so dbms_aq is somehow visible, but not in my procedure.

Comment: Just to clarify: You executed the "desc dbms_aq" as the same user you want to compile the procedure with, right?

Comment: Yes, it was done in the same SQLDeveloper session.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Does it work if you do...

```
SYS.DBMS_AQ
```

instead of just

```
DBMS_AQ
```

If so, you're missing a synonym.

**EDIT**:

If you're now getting "PLS-00201: identifier 'SYS.DBMS_AQ" then I'd double check your grants.

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON SYS.DBMS_AQ to <your-user>;
```

Also, just to confirm, you've granted the execute privilege *directly* to the user, and not via a role?

Comment: No. In SQL Developer I added sys. then code completion propose dbms_aq, but after that I can choose between AQ$_DEQUEUE(), ..., UNREGISTER(...), but there is no enqueue_options_t nor message_properties_t.

Comment: After I added sys. Oracle changed error message to: Error(6,21): PLS-00201: identifier 'SYS.DBMS_AQ' must be declared

Comment: It worked after I granted from sys user not user as sysdba. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. If you are sure that DBMS_AQ exist, make sure you give grant with SYS user not SYSTEM.
Because SYS owns the data dictionary, it's considered a bit more special than SYSTEM.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34896547)

Answer (score -1):

In order to use objects in stored procedures, you must have grants WITH GRANT OPTION.

In this case you smust have 
GRANT EXECUTE ON SYS.DBMS_AQ **WITH GRANT OPTION** to ;