# Oracle: problem with constructing JMS message

Tags: oracle, plsql, jms, advanced-queuing

After some struggle with [Oracle Advanced Queuing and dbms_aq package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378721/pl-sql-function-in-oracle-cannot-see-dbmsaq)
I encountered another issue. I copied code from Oracle tutorials
but when I compile this code:

```
create or replace
procedure jms_test(msg varchar2)
is
    id                 pls_integer;
    message            sys.aq$_jms_stream_message;
    enqueue_options    dbms_aq.enqueue_options_t;
    message_properties dbms_aq.message_properties_t;
begin
    message := sys.aq$_jms_stream_message.construct(0);
    message.set_string_property('FROM', 'TEST');
    id := message.clear_body(-1);
end;
```

it complains with:

```
Error(9,40): PLS-00302: component 'CONSTRUCT' must be declared
Error(10,10): PLS-00302: component 'SET_STRING_PROPERTY' must be declared
Error(11,16): PLS-00302: component 'CLEAR_BODY' must be declared
```

I think this code works out of procedure body, because I tried with success
recipes from [What's in my JMS queue](http://rwijk.blogspot.com/2009/02/whats-in-my-jms-queue.html)?

My Oracle version is:
Oracle9i Enterprise Edition Release 9.2.0.1.0 - Production

Any idea what can be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a database version problem. AQ$_JMS_STREAM_MESSAGE has a construct method in 10G but not in 9i. What version of Oracle Server are you using?

Comment: Sorry, version is in your post. So your code probaly won't run on a Oracle 9i database

Comment: Yes, this probably is version problem. I haven't checked version info from Oracle manual. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like grants again

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON SYS.aq$_jms_stream_message To <your-user>;
```

Does:

```
desc sys.aq$_jms_stream_message
```

work in SQL*Plus from both the SYS + your schema?

Note that SYS.AQ$_JMS_STREAM_MESSAGE is a datbase object/type, whereas SYS.DBMS_AQ is a package

**EDIT**

Ok... maybe the TYPE body is missing / invalid.  What does:

```
SELECT owner, object_name, object_type, status
FROM   dba_OBJECTS
WHERE  OBJECT_NAME = 'AQ$_JMS_STREAM_MESSAGE'
```

return?

Comment: GRANT succeeded, desc works from both schemas, but function cannot compile.

Comment: Result of select: SYS, AQ$_JMS_STREAM_MESSAGE, TYPE, VALID